# Vertical Scrollerviewer inside panorama item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I am trying to add a `scrollerviewer` inside a panorama item. Here is my `XAML`

```
           phone:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="483" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
    </StackPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item1" >
            <ScrollViewer Height="483">
            <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="72"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply .. but the same is not working in the above XAML

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Grid. Row where the panorama item placed has not any height set.
Try using Grid. Row=* for the panorama row.
And set 'Height=Auto' for your stackpanel